# OPA Gatekeeper: match everything

Tags: kubernetes, opa

In OPA Gatekeeper, is there a configuration for `spec.match.kinds` in a constraint to match everything?

I've tried using a bunch of combinations, like this a one:

```yaml
...
spec:
  match:
    kinds:
      - apiGroups: ["*"]
        kinds: ["*"]
...
```

And none of them work. Is this even possible in OPA Gatekeeper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked well:

```
spec:
  match: {}
```